# Compiling ipopt for ipoptr on Mac

Tags: r, ipopt

How to compile `ipopt` on Mac OS X with natively tuned Accelerate BLAS/LAPACK in order to be able to use it from `R` with `ipoptr`?

Answer (score -1):

There are several configure options that need to be specified:

1. Option to enable the necessary dynamic loading from R add: **`--with-pic`**
2. In order to enable native BLAS/LAPACK add both: **`--with-blas="-framework Accelerate" --with-lapack=""`**

Resulting configure command:

```
../configure --disable-shared \ 
F77=gfortran FFLAGS="-fexceptions -m64 -fbackslash" \
CFLAGS="-fno-common -no-cpp-precomp -fexceptions -arch x86_64 -m64" \
CXXFLAGS="-fno-common -no-cpp-precomp -fexceptions -arch x86_64 -m64" \
--with-blas="-framework Accelerate" --with-lapack="" --with-pic
```